# Kendo Multiselect data disappear after kendo UI 2016 upgrade

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, upgrade

We were using kendo 2013 and have upgraded to version 2016.
After this upgrade we are facing an issue with kendo multi-select 
control which uses ajax call to bind the data.(No issue with pre-filled Multi-select controls).The multi-select gets filled with respect to the data selected on a kendo dropdown.
The multi-select value disappear in some scenarios.

Please see the videos for more information.

http://www.screencast.com/t/0xY9SPuQj

http://www.screencast.com/t/gVH2rE5365

Following are the controls used.

****  Drop Down *********

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedViewState)
   .OptionLabel("--Select--")
   .DataSource(source => source
                .Read(read => read.Action("LoadViewState", "CommandForm")).ServerFiltering(true))
  .Events(e => e.Change("onViewStateChange"))
           .DataTextField("Name")
           .DataValueField("ViewStateId")
           .Deferred()
           .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 180px" }))
```

**** Multi select *********

```
@(Html.Kendo().MultiSelectFor(model => model.Payer)
           .AutoBind(true)
           .Deferred()
         .DataTextField("Name")
         .DataValueField("Id")
         .Placeholder("Select Payers...")
         .DataSource(source =>
         {
             source.Read(read =>
             {
                 read.Action("LoadPayerMultiSelect", "CommandForm");
             })
             .ServerFiltering(true);
         })
          .ItemTemplate("<dl>" +
                         "<dd class='first-item'>${ data.Name }</dd>" +
                         "<dd> ${ data.Code }</dd>" +
                         "</dl>")
         .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:95%;height:26px;overflow: auto;position:relative;" })
             )
```

*********  Code used to fill multi-select  ********

```
function onViewStateChange(e) {
    var value = $("#SelectedViewState").val();
    var dropDown = e.sender;
    var query = new kendo.data.Query(e.sender.dataSource.data());
    var data = query.filter({ field: "ViewStateId", operator: "eq", value: value }).data;
    if (data != undefined && data.length!=0) {
        var setting = data[0].Setting;
        var model = JSON.parse(setting).ViewStates;
        var payerListData = '[' + model.Payer + ']';//data in  model.Payer "{"Id":"40eb0d8c-6021-403c-92b0-efdc4865ef7c","Name":"(HOSPICE) ANDROSCOGGIN12"}"
        var payerLists = JSON.parse(payerListData);
        var payerSelect = $('#Payer').data('kendoMultiSelect');
        var payerGuidArray = [];
        $.each(payerLists, function (index, objValue) {
            payerGuidArray.push(objValue.Id);
        });
        payerSelect.dataSource.data(payerLists);
        payerSelect.value(payerGuidArray);
    }
}
```

Please assist me to resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance..